# How to upload Random audio file in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I want to upload audio file for multiple thread from Http Request in JMeter. I have a folder which contains a number of audio file. I want that it take audio file from folder randomly. How can i do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can go with Dmitri answer.

**Another approach:**

If possible, you can change the audio files names like this - `audio1.mp3`, audio2.mp3..etc

In the HTTP request `file path` field, update the file name as (assuming you have 100 files),

`c:\path\to\audio${__Random(1,100)}.mp3`

`${__Random(1,100)}` --> Generates a random number between 1 and 100

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) to dynamically get random file path from the specified folder.

To do so:

1. Add Beanshell PreProcessor as a child of the request which performs upload
2. Put the following code into the PreProcessor's "Script" area:

   ```
   File folder = new File("/path/to/your/folder/with/audiofiles");
   File[] audioFiles = folder.listFiles();
   Random rnd = new Random();
   vars.put("CURRENT_FILE", audioFiles[rnd.nextInt(audioFiles.length)].getAbsolutePath());
   ```
3. Refer random file location as `${CURRENT_FILE}` where required

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on Beanshell scripting in Apache JMeter.

Comment: @Ankur, you should accept this as answer. Dmitri took some time for you to clarify your issue.

Comment: I am getting error:            jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: Cannot find BeanShell: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bsh.Interpreter

Comment: Can you see file `bsh-xx.jar` under /lib folder of your JMeter installation? If not - either reinstall JMeter as it should be shipped or download it from http://www.beanshell.org/download.html, drop to /lib folder and restart JMeter

Comment: Thanks @DmitriT i placed bsh-xx.jar to /lib folder and it worked. Thanks for your great help.